# Jquery / css error on Internet Explorer 8

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

I have a jquery / CSS code that works well, but not on Internet Explorer 8.

It's a slider. But it doesn't work when you use Internet Explorer 8. In all other browsers it works great. Can anyone plase help with with the code?

**[JsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tobbecokta/Uum8j)**

```
    /* slider */
.range {
float:left;
margin-top: 12px;
width: 125px;
}

.ui-slider-wrapper {
position: relative;
padding: 16px 0 0 0;
height: 212px;
width: 24px;
text-align: left;
background: #1f8fb5;
/* CSS3 */
-moz-border-radius: 12px;
-webkit-border-radius: 12px;
border-radius: 12px;
-moz-text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #267f9d;
-webkit-text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #267f9d;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #267f9d;
}

.ui-slider {
position: relative;
float: left;
padding-right: 104px;
height: 196px;
width: 24px;
}

.ui-slider .ui-slider-tooltip {
display: none;
}

.ui-slider .screenReaderContext {
position: absolute;
width: 0;
height: 0;
overflow: hidden;
left: -999999999px;
}

.ui-slider ol {
position: relative;
left: 55px;
top: -4px;
width: 88px;
}

.ui-slider li {
width: 88px;
margin-bottom: 9px;
}

.ui-slider-handle {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
display: block;
margin-bottom: -16px; /*offset*/
height: 32px;
width: 24px;
text-indent: -9999em;
background: red;
z-index: 1;
}

.ui-slider-range {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
width: 24px;
background: #ccc;
}
```

​

Br,
Tobias

Comment: Please tell us what problems you're seeing -- "doesn't work" isn't a very good description of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

from the top of my head I remember reading keeping `padding` and `margin` 0px for cross browser compatibility .